# Signal handling in Python after double fork

Tags: python, signals, fork, daemon

Strange behaviour of Python after double fork to create a textbook-like daemon. When registering a SIGTERM handler in the grandchild after forking twice, the handler is never called up signal reception for the correct PID, ie. the one of the grandchild.

Full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/ChajHKGg).

```
import sys
import signal
import time
import os
import logging

class Handler(object):
    def __init__(self, stdin='/dev/null', stdout='/dev/null', stderr='/dev/null'):
        self.stdin = stdin
        self.stdout = stdout
        self.stderr = stderr

    def daemon(self):
          logging.debug('Before first fork')
          try:
              pid = os.fork()
              if pid > 0:
                  #exit first parent
                  sys.exit(0)
          except OSError, e:
                sys.stderr.write("fork #1 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
                sys.exit(1)
          # decouple from parent environment
          logging.debug('After first fork')
          os.chdir("/")
          os.setsid()
          os.umask(0)

         # do second fork
         try:
             pid = os.fork()
             if pid > 0:
                  # exit from second parent
                 sys.exit(0)
          except OSError as e:
                 sys.stderr.write("fork #2 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
                 sys.exit(1)
          # Redirect standard file descriptors
          logging.debug('After second fork')
          sys.stdout.flush()
          sys.stderr.flush()
          si = file(self.stdin, 'r')
          so = file(self.stdout, 'w+')
          se = file(self.stderr, 'w+', 0)
          os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
          os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
          os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
          logging.debug('before setting signal handlers')
          signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.sigint_handler)
          logging.debug('before while')
          while True:
                sys.stdout.write('.')
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(1)

     def sigint_handler(self, signum, frame):
           logging.debug('In signal handler')
           os.killpg(0, signal.SIGTERM)

def main():
     logging.basicConfig(filename='log', filemode='w',
     level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

     han = Handler()
     han.daemon()
     ##########

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What is the issue? Or am I simply missing the forest for the trees?

Comment: What logging messages are output?  And can you correct your indentation please?

Comment: Here's the log:  2017-05-10 14:25:22,246 root         DEBUG    Before first fork  
2017-05-10 14:25:22,250 root         DEBUG    After first fork  
2017-05-10 14:25:22,258 root         DEBUG    After second fork  
2017-05-10 14:25:22,258 root         DEBUG    before setting signal handlers  
2017-05-10 14:25:22,258 root         DEBUG    before while

Comment: Sorry about the formatting but the markup seems to be screwed up. You can download the source code from monochromec.com/sigterm.py if the pastebin dump is not usable.